# Unresolved reference: setLifecycleOwner in AndroidX

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, camera-view

> MainActivity.kt: (41, 16): Unresolved reference: setLifecycleOwner
>
> Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

My app uses AndroidX, in my gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

My Code in onCreate function in MainActivity.tk:

```
val camera = findViewById<View>(R.id.camera)
    camera.setLifecycleOwner(this)
```

Trying to implment the [CameraView](https://natario1.github.io/CameraView/about/getting-started.html).

Comment: What exactly is `this`? Is it an `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: @CommonsWare ``import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`` and the 
 ``class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { }``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cast your library view type to android basic `View` which hasn't such method.
You should change your `findViewById<View>` to `findViewById<CameraView>`